# Android: How to make video from set of images

Tags: android, video, android-camera

I'm creating an app in android. In this app i've to create a video file(mp4, 3gp) from the images that are stored in the sdcard of the device. Is there any solution for this in android or we have to use any another api for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Creating a video from single frames? What FPS rate do you expect? You can create something similar to a .gif using multiple pictures, but it won't actually be a .gif file. Theoretically you can make a video using many pictures but it won't be a video extension like .mp4 What's your goal?

Comment: here i want to create the .mp4 file from the selected images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not provide any built-in APIs which would allow to create video files from single frames. Consider using Sony Vegas or Adobe After Effects instead.

However you can emulate the video effect in an `ImageView` (not really a viable solution indeed, but would do in some simple cases). For that you would need to create an array containing your frames and loop through the array using a `CountDownTimer` or similar. Setting the next frame in the `ImageView` with of a tick rate of 40ms would correspond to a frame rate of 25 FPS. You could also provide background sounds using [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) or [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MJPEGgenerator.java](https://code.google.com/p/javadrone/source/browse/src/com/codeminders/ardrone/util/MJPEGGenerator.java) to create an AVI from a set of jpg images